# Group of matrix isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

I have 2 groups:

- general linear $ k  \times k $ with $\cdot$
- top-triangle matrix $ n \times n $ with 1 on main diagonal. Operation is $\cdot$ too

Is there isomorphism for any any non-trivial $n,k$ i.e $n \neq 2 \ or \  k \neq 1$ over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$?

If no, how can I prove it?

Comment: Did you intend $\mathbb{N}$ to be the set of integers? natural numbers?

Comment: @BillCook, I mixed it up with $\mathbb{Q}$, fixed now

Comment: Upper-triangular matrices form solvable groups, general linear groups are not solvable (for $k>1$). Thus they cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upper-triangular matrices form solvable groups, general linear groups are not solvable (for $k>1$). Thus they cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Upper triangular matrix groups with 1 on the main diagonal are even nilpotent.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason is that if the field is of characteristics $0$ then all elements (except the identity matrix) in the set upper triangle matrix with 1 on the main diagonal do not have finite order. However, there are lots of matrix in $ GL_k(F)$ has finite order. For instance, those have $-1$ or $1$ on the main diagonal and $0$ elsewhere.

However, this argument doesn't work for fields of finite characteristics.